# Material Derivate of a vector field

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces, vector-analysis, cylindrical-coordinates

Given the vector field $\vec{v}=wr\vec{i}_{\theta}-v_0\vec{i}_r$ (cylindrical-coordinates)

I'm supposed to find the local and convectiv acceleration/derivation

$$\frac{Df}{Dt}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}+v\cdot\nabla f$$

For the local derivation I should get $\frac{\partial \vec{v}}{\partial t}=0$?

I'm not sure on how I do the convectiv derivation, It gets messy really fast and I get confused. Do I first take $v\cdot\nabla$ or $\nabla f$? If you could show me with an example, it would be really appriciated!

Comment: The order does not matter. In cartesian coordinates, it's $v \cdot \nabla f = v_i \partial_i f$

Answer (score 0):

$$D\vec{v}=\partial_{t}\vec{v}+(\vec{v}\cdot\nabla)\vec{v}=$$
$$=\frac{\partial\vec{v}}{\partial{t}}+v_{r}\frac{\partial\vec{v}}{\partial{r}}+v_{\varphi}\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial\vec{v}}{\partial\varphi}+v_{z}\frac{\partial\vec{v}}{\partial{z}}$$